# Generate Yii translation message files

Tags: php, bash, internationalization, yii

I am interested to know is there a script or otherway available to collect and generate Yii translation messages in a controller/project

Eg. If I have the following codes in a controller

```
Yii::t('blog', 'Your name');
Yii::t('category', 'Category name');
```

It should generate English translation message files as blog.php and category.php with above strings in messages directory. Please let me know if somebody knows a way. Thanks

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There's no need to reinvent the wheel. You can use `yiic` for that (if you go to the framework folder and type in `yiic help message` you will get all the info to need about it's usage). For convenience, I'm going to paste it here.

> USAGE   yiic message path/to/config/file
>
> DESCRIPTION   This command searches for messages to be translated in
>   the specified   source files and compiles them into PHP arrays as
>   message source.
>
> PARAMETERS  * config-file: required, the path of the configuration
>   file. You can find an example in framework/messages/config.php.
>
> The file can be placed anywhere and must be a valid PHP script
>   which    returns an array of name-value pairs. Each name-value pair
>   represents    a configuration option.
>
> The following options are available:
>
> - sourcePath: string, root directory of all source files.
> - messagePath: string, root directory containing message translations.
> - languages: array, list of language codes that the extracted messages
>      should be translated to. For example, array('zh_cn','en_au').
> - fileTypes: array, a list of file extensions (e.g. 'php', 'xml').
>      Only the files whose extension name can be found in this list
>      will be processed. If empty, all files will be processed.
> - exclude: array, a list of directory and file exclusions. Each
>      exclusion can be either a name or a path. If a file or directory name
>      or path matches the exclusion, it will not be copied. For example,
>      an exclusion of '.svn' will exclude all files and directories whose
>      name is '.svn'. And an exclusion of '/a/b' will exclude file or
>      directory 'sourcePath/a/b'.
> - translator: the name of the function for translating messages.
>      Defaults to 'Yii::t'. This is used as a mark to find messages to be
>      translated.
> - overwrite: if message file must be overwritten with the merged messages.
> - removeOld: if message no longer needs translation it will be removed,
>      instead of being enclosed between a pair of '@@' marks.

You should modify (and move) the example config file and you're all set. Be sure to use full paths (ie. `C:\path\to\project` on Windows or `/var/www/your/project` on *nix)

Comment: very nice! thanks for this. Now i recall this kind of stuff when i just started Yii exploring but forgot after "basic stuff" :)
(Tested just now and collected all my translations)
+1

Comment: Excellent. It works more than expected. Thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 3):

I could give you input how to start and you can write your own script. I found this good for me for now :)

### Create component components/Translation.php

```
public function missing($messageEvent) {        
    Yii::log(
        "'".$messageEvent->message."' => '',",
        'translation',
        $messageEvent->category.'.'.$messageEvent->language
    );
}
```

}

### Edit configuration file config/main.php

```
'components' => array(
      //...
      'log' => array(
            array(
                'class'=>'CFileLogRoute',
                'levels'=>'translation',
                'logFile'=>'translations.log',
            ),
            //...                
      ),

       'messages' => array(
            //'class' => 'CDbMessageSource',
            'onMissingTranslation' => array('Translation', 'missing'),
            //'sourceMessageTable' => 'source_message',
            //'translatedMessageTable' => 'message'
       ),
)
```

### Result

You will end up with `translation.php` file in your log file directory and file contents will be something like:

```
 2012/06/28 09:45:00 [translation] [Site.lv] 'MyStringInSource' => '',
 ....
```

depending on your configuration.
So you can copy `'MyStringInSource' => '',` part and put in corresponding translation file.

This is helpful in development process because it will grow translation.log file with missing translation (repeatedly) until you translate these.

Hope it gives you idea.

Answer (score 1):

That sounds like a job for `grep` and a regular expression. Search for this:

```
Yii::t\s*\(\s*('(?:[^']|(?<=\\)')*'|"(?:[^"]|(?<=\\)")*")\s*,\s*('(?:[^']|(?<=\\)')*'|"(?:[^"]|(?<=\\)")*")\s*\)
```

Since the above is unfortunately unreadable, I 'll break it down a bit:

```
Yii::t\s*\(\s*##PATTERN##\s*,\s*##PATTERN##\s*\)
```

This obviously matches a call to `Yii::t` taking care to account for whitespace. The secret sauce is `##PATTERN##`, which is repeated twice. `##PATTERN##` is

```
('(?:[^']|(?<=\\)')*'|"(?:[^"]|(?<=\\)")*")
```

The above matches either `'([^']|(?<=\\)')*'` (a singly quoted string) or `"([^"]|(?<=\\)")*"` (a doubly quoted string). Non-capturing groups (`?:`) have been used to disregard interim results that are of no interest.

After matching with this regex, capturing group #1 will hold the translation file name (e.g. `'blog'`) and group #2 will hold the string name (e.g. `'Your name'`).