# Yii: localization in Navbar with images

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, yii, localization

It would be nice to have a Dropdown menu with several flags.Is there a way to show a image like a Flag in the navigation when I use twitter-bootstrap?
If I select one flag, the language and the flag should change.

I can show the bootstrap supported Icons but they contain no flags.

I hope some can help me. below is my navigation.

```
        $this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbNavbar', array(
            'type' => 'null', // null or 'inverse'
            'brand' => '<img src="http://localhost/images/logo.gif">',
            'brandUrl' => 'localhost',
            'collapse' => true, // requires bootstrap-responsive.css
            'items' => array(
                array(
                    'class' => 'bootstrap.widgets.TbMenu',
                    'type' => 'pills', // '', 'tabs', 'pills' (or 'list')
                    'items' => array(
                        array('label' => 'Home', 'url' => array('/site/index')),
                        array('label' => 'user create', 'url' => array('/account/user/create')),
                        array('label' => 'Contact', 'url' => array('/site/contact')),
                        array('label' => 'User', 'url' => array('/account/user/index')),
                    ),
                ),
                array(
                    'class' => 'bootstrap.widgets.TbMenu',
                    'type' => 'pills', // '', 'tabs', 'pills' (or 'list')
                    'htmlOptions' => array('class' => 'pull-right'),

                    'items' => array(

        /**Added to show, that here should appear the flag*/
                        array('label' => '','htmlOptions'=> array('src'=>'http://localhost/images/german.png'), 'url' => ''),

                        array('label' => 'Sign in', 'url' => array('/account/signup/login'), 'visible' => Yii::app()->user->isGuest),
                        array('label' => 'Sign up', 'url' => array('/account/signup/registration'), 'visible' => Yii::app()->user->isGuest),
                        array('label' => Yii::app()->user->name , 'url' => '#', 'items' => array(
                                array('label' => 'Action', 'url' => '#'),
                                array('label' => 'Another action', 'url' => '#'),
                                array('label' => 'Something else here', 'url' => '#'),
                                '---',
                                array('label' => 'Logout', 'url' => array('/account/signup/logout')),
                            ),'visible' => !Yii::app()->user->isGuest),
                        ),
                ),
            ),
        ));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you noticed, you'll need flag icons to start with. You could, for example, use [these](http://flag-sprites.com). You may or may not need to modify the returned CSS a little to suit your needs.

Next you need to create the switch-URLs. This essentially boils down to having the current URL AND the language selection as get parameter. Create a canonical link for the site you are currently on and attach `?lang=<target>`. Another approach would be to simply attach the switch part to the current URL and use that instead. I outlined something like that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19605392/yii-query-string-do-not-change-when-click-language-picker/19607320#19607320).

Next you need to make sure your application can actually handle localization. I have no idea how far along that road you are yet, so you may want to read [this](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.i18n). To actually have the languages switch on request you can do the following in `protected/components/Controller.php`

```
public function init() {
  parent:init();

  if (null === Yii::app()->user->getState('lang') || null !== Yii::app()->request->getQuery('lang', null)) {
        Yii::app()->user->setState('lang', Yii::app()->request->getQuery('lang','defaultLanguage'));
    }
    Yii::app()->setLanguage(Yii::app()->user->getState('lang'));

}
```

This way, wherever you are, the language gets set based on the get parameter and persists as long as the session exists. You may even want to replace 'defaultLanguage' with a call to a function that determines a default value e.g. based on the user agent string of the browser or the visitor's IP.

To generate the language files you need/want take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11232039/generate-yii-translation-message-files).

To create the necessary links inside the menu you can either create a function returning the appropriate array or switch the values such as `label` and `url` with a ternary operator, e.g. `'label' => ('en' == Yii::app()->language) ? 'Switch to Spanish' : 'Switch to English'`. However, this only properly works with binary decisions. If you want to offer more languages you should consider a different approach, such as the function I mentioned.

Comment: This is awesome! Thanks a lot. I just added your suggestions to my code and it really works fine. But are the CSS Spirits free for comercial use?

Comment: The sprites are, as described on the site I linked, "available for free use for any purpose with no requirement for attribution". The full license information is available in the sidebar to the right.